# A-Frame WebVR present non-stereo view

Tags: aframe, webvr

Is it possible to have A-Frames present a non stereo camera feed on screen while the user is in VR? For instance, have it display just the right eye camera's feed, or maybe use a 3rd camera?

Answer (score 0):

There's a stereo component to show different things to different eyes. May not work with latest versions, but the approach should be the same: https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component

Uses three.js layers